# How to target tablet devices with CSS queries

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target tablets with a own css however I do not get it to work. I know there is a way to target iPad specifically but are there no better ways? I want to target Android tablets too but phones such as Samsung Nexus are misinterpreted as a tablet in the way I am doing it now.

Comment: Have you tried media queries?

Comment: maybe you should post how you do it now, so we can tell whats wrong with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use different style sheets according to device resolution

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" href="mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="tablet.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

[twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), wich is well known for its support of different devices, uses the following media queries:

```
// Landscape phones and down
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }

// Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { ... }

// Large desktop
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .. }
```

so it seems like devices where width is > `480px` and <= `980px` (or <= `768px` if you only want to detect portrait ones) are detected as tablets.

Comment: Note: If you're Copying this answer's code, remember to change the comment style to /**/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Media-types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types) declarations. But I guess its up to the browser to actually make use of these. Also have a look at [DetectMobileBrowser](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think is media queries. And there are lots of scripts, which enable the media queries.

### [Response.js](http://responsejs.com/)

It has been also included in [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). So, you can use which you prefer.